# Using "RandomFunction" to simulate a Itoprocess with Random initial condition

Tags: random

I have an itoprocess such as:

```
ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]vx[t] == -vx[t]*\[DifferentialD]t + 
  2*\[DifferentialD]w[t], \[DifferentialD]x[t] == vx[t]*\[DifferentialD]t}, 
  x[t], {{x, vx}, {x0, 0}}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
```

I want to simulate this process 10000 time by using RandomFunction. However, I need the initial value of x (x0) to be Normal distributed such as `x0 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1]]`. But the `ItoProcess` in *Mathematica* doesn't support random initial condition.

Is there any method to solve this problem?

Comment: Just add the random initial condition to the whole curve after it was sampled?

Comment: Thank you for helping! I think it works for random X0, but sometimes I also want the initial velocity vx0 to be random, which may not be applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would be helpful:

```
proc := With[{x0 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]},
  ItoProcess[
   {\[DifferentialD]vx[t] == -vx[t]*\[DifferentialD]t + 2*\[DifferentialD]w[t], \[DifferentialD]x[t] ==  vx[t]*\[DifferentialD]t},
   x[t], {{x, vx}, {x0, 0}}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
 ]
```

then

```
With[{n = 350},
  TemporalData[Nest[Join[#, {RandomFunction[proc, {0, 29, 1}]}] &, {}, n]] // ListLinePlot
 ]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! Yesterday I also try to solve this by using the "Table" such as "TemporalData[Table[Randomfunction[ItoProcess[...{{x, vx}, {RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1]], 0}}, t, ...],{0,3,0.001}],10000]]". I will try if the two method are both applicable!

Comment: You are welcome! I haven't tried what you are suggesting but it seems plausible that it would work *in principle*. Please note that the amount of data points you are generating is substantial and I have doubts whether either approach will be *practical* when time/memory considerations are taken into account (on an *old* machine the estimated time to make 10000 repetitions with the specified step is approx. 15 mins and 257MB in size); perhaps you should consider the suggestions in the comments and/or the other answers as *viable* alternatives *for the volume of your data requirements*

Answer (score 0):

I think this is essentially what @HenrikSchumacher suggested:

```
nsim = 10; 
ito = RandomFunction[ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]vx[t] == -vx[t]*\[DifferentialD]t + 
  2*\[DifferentialD]w[t], \[DifferentialD]x[t] == vx[t]*\[DifferentialD]t},
  x[t], {{x, vx}, {x0, 0}}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]], {0., 5., 0.01}]
ListLinePlot[ito /. x0 -> #] & /@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], nsim]
```

[image: 10 Ito realizations]

```
Mean[ito /. x0 -> #] & /@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], nsim]
(* {0.264367, 0.555122, -1.45459, 0.663994, -3.19353, -0.383676, 0.51233, -1.1766, 
    1.54617, 1.6006} *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! In my problem I need to derive the distribution of X at some fixed time. So I also have to use orders such as "["SliceData",t]". I will try if I can define the 10000 trajectories as a TemporalData by using your method. Thanks again!